# Congratulations! Music: Practice & Theory is graduating!

Tags: discussion, graduation

It's a big day. You've been cleared for graduation by the Stack Exchange Community Team! Music met our threshold for [graduation-worthy sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) and after a review, the Community Team determined that you're good to go. Reaching 'mature community' status is a big milestone, and you should be very proud.

What does this mean exactly? Graduation works in two phases. Starting today, you'll receive the following benefits

- You will soon have an election for community-voted moderators
- You will no longer see the "beta" label attached to your site's name
- You will become eligible for question migration paths with the rest of the network
- You will be able to select your own community ads

In the coming months, the site will receive a full design from one of our designers, which will be packaged with an increase in the amount of reputation needed to access each privilege. It's no secret that our backlog for site designs is long, and although you're looking at wait of several months, we wanted to [give you the things we could give](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation) you now. There are also bound to be bugs as the new process gets rolled out so if you come across anything out of place, please report it on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) using the [graduating-sites] tag.

This site has reached this point because of your generous contributions. Together, you've created a valuable resource that helps people. Congratulations on all you've accomplished.

Comment: Yay! Paaaaaaaaaaaaaartyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy!!! :) Thanks Grace!

Comment: Excellent news Grace - thanks. Feel free to point the designers at http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/q/92/104 for the community's thoughts on design so far.

Comment: What do you mean by "eligible" for migration pathways?

Comment: @JacobSwanson it means that we can migrate to other sites, whereas now it was more complicated

Comment: up until now our only official migration path was to our meta, and every other one was a mod request. Now we can look at stats on where we have migrated posts to, and have the most common on a shortlist. In fact - I need to make a meta post on that...

Comment: http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/q/2284/104

Comment: possible duplicate of [Music SE is graduating. Congratulations!](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/q/925/1941)

Comment: Can you give us an idea when the elections will begin?

Answer (score 21):

I don't think if we have had a definite answer from the council, but we've [discussed about](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/926/7356) a kind of music rendering for the site. Don't know if this is something we can have, or if we can have before the design along with our graduation, but it will the help the community a lot; writing posts would be much easier.

The two discussions:

- [Decision: Request Lilypond support from the SE developers](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/913/decision-request-lilypond-support-from-the-se-developers)
- [Is there some sort of mark-up for music notation?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/is-there-some-sort-of-mark-up-for-music-notation)

Answer (score 9):

Also a simple "insert symbol" functionality would be helpful. This is to enable simple things in text like accidentals for note names Example B♭, C♯ etc.
See [Suggestion: Make music symbols available to copy in to text. (♭ ♮ ♯ ♪ ♩)](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/264/249)

My suggestion is toolbar buttons in the post editor (or a dropdown box with "symbols"). This would be a site-specific section in the toolbar area at the right of the standard buttons.

Comment: I honestly don't think we need the eighth note or quarter note, but I believe we can benefit from other symbols like roman numerals for analysis and all the accidentals like you suggested.

Comment: The accidentals **are** available already as html codes: `&flat;`, `&sharp;` and `&natural;`. Which is pretty optimal, really (except it doesn't work in comments).

Comment: @leftaroundabout I think it would be much easier for newbies and much faster to everyone to simply copy them from some source near the answer box, rather than remembering the html codes

Comment: I agree that we don't need the note symbols. Only symbols that are natural to use in text as note name additions etc. You say the &flat; &sharp; and &natural; won't work in comments, but I guess this could be made work for this site. For non-programmers, this would not be enough though, as they would not know how to insert it. We need UI for it, at least in the post editor. In the comment section, it is already a help you can show that says something about mini-Markdown formatting. We could add information about flat sharp and natural encoding there.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: We also need to be able to insert this in a code section, (for example as a line of chords that are aligned to text position) where html encoding will not be respected. Those cases you have to use the actual characters, like this: `C♯  A♭`.

Comment: For what it's worth, somebody on [Mi Yodeya](http://mi.yodeya.com) built a user script to add a Hebrew keyboard, and later SE added the functionality officially.  Whatever they put in place to support that could help here.  (Obviously the actual keys will be different.)  If you want to see what it looks like, start to create a post and then click on the א next to the "insert image" icon.

Answer (score 6):

It's great to hear this [announcement again](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/925/music-se-is-graduating-congratulations), but now it's over the month mark and we've had little to no indication of when our elections will be or how far back in the design queue we are.

Please don't let this be like the last time and just leave us hanging without any information for almost a year. Just little updates every once in a while go a long way and will keep us attune to this process instead of trying to guess about what's going on and when. It's not much, but it's something we deserve as a community.

Comment: status-ongoing :-)