# ABCjs renderer is doing something very strange with short snippets

Tags: bug, abcjs

##### Note that sometimes ctrl+F5 fixes this but sometimes it doesn't!!

Some short abcjs snippets are being rendered wildly incorrectly, with a (constant) weird preamble. I will lead with a *screenshot* of [the meta question for abcjs documentation](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2782) :

[image]

Note in particular the sequence of notes actually rendered: C e a e d a (with a turn) a C

Here is a live short snippet:

```
X:1
M:4/4
L:1/4
K:C
C C C C | D D  D D | E E E  E | C C C C | D D  D D | E E E  E ||
```

Note the exact same preamble, and you can also see CCCC etc being rendered (albeit in the wrong duration)

It *seems* to be linked to [too short a snippet](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3697/6954) but I don't know a good cutoff length, or what other features might trigger / not trigger the problem.

Comment: The Ctrl+F5 worked for me on this page, and on your answer to [What does “three on four, five on seven, etc” mean?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/115921/what-does-three-on-four-five-on-seven-etc-mean).  Maybe the browser was caching an old stylesheet?